# Heroku git master push

Tags: python, heroku, pycharm, plotly-dash

I'm new to heroku, but I've been following the documentation to the letter. I am deploying my dash app to heroku. The setup was going well until the final master push

```
> (venv) -MacBook-Air-3 heroku % git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 12155, done.
Counting objects: 100% (12155/12155), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2900/2900), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12155/12155), 15.08 MiB | 1.53 MiB/s, done.
Total 12155 (delta 9145), reused 12155 (delta 9145)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.12
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hBrotli==1.0.9        
(from -r /tmp/build_77052133/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for hBrotli==1.0.9 (from -r                                /tmp/build_77052133/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

> 

I went to the requirements.txt that I created with pip3 freeze >requirements.txt as per the documentation and indeed on line 1 there was hBrotli== 1.0.9. I am not familiar with hBrotli and don't use it for my code and can't seem to find any information about it. I'm not sure what the error message is implying.

Comment: [Brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) is a compression format developed by Google. I would add the url to it in your requirements.txt file.

Comment: due to some typo, Brotli has become hBrotli and it is complaining that there is no package found named hBrotli with a given version because hBrotli is not a thing.

Answer (score 0):

there is no package named **hBrotli** it may be due to some typo just change **hBrotli** to **Brotli**

Answer (score 0):

This is the package that you are looking for https://pypi.org/project/Brotli/ so just change the hBrotli to Brotli

Or just do `pip install Brotli`

Also if needed change imports into `from brotli import nameOfClass`